# SublimeLinter: WARNING: jshint deactivated, cannot locate 'jshint'

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

This just happened completely randomly. All I did was restart Sublime and next I know I had to re-set the path to git.exe and SublimeLinter jshint is broken. I've removed and re-installed SublimeLinter and SublimLinter-jshint in various orders to try to fix it.

I also installed jshint globally with npm.

SublimeLinter default/user settings:

```
{
    "default": {
        "debug": false,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "background",
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": ["C:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\jshint\\bin"]
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "python django": "python",
            "html 5": "html",
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "php": "html"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

console:

```
SublimeLinter: jshint linter loaded 
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.commands
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.sublimelinter
plugins loaded
SublimeLinter: debug mode: on 
SublimeLinter: temp directory: c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\SublimeLinter3 
SublimeLinter: computed PATH from system:
C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jshint\bin
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\
C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Lenovo
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Client Security Solution
C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Client Security Solution
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenLDAP\kfw\Binary
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
C:\Python27

SublimeLinter: WARNING: jshint deactivated, cannot locate 'jshint' 
SublimeLinter: found existing HTML syntax, version 3 
SublimeLinter: found existing Rails syntax, version 1 
found 3 files for base name Main.sublime-menu
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2014-07-30 10:51:51, next run at 2014-07-30 11:51:51 or after
```

Comment: SublimeLinter requires you to have jshint in your path. Have you tried opening a terminal window and seeing what happens if you type `jshint --version`? You should see something like `jshint v2.5.0` as a response.

Comment: oh... I thought SublimeLinter knowing the path was it (a bit redundant then...?). Alright. Put it inside PATH and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [SublimeLinter documentation](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/installation.html), it requires you to have linter executables in your path.

> Most linter plugins require you to install a linter binary or library
>   and configure your PATH so that SublimeLinter can find it. You must
>   follow the linter plugin’s installation instructions to successfully
>   use it.

Have you tried opening a terminal window and seeing what happens if you type `jshint --version`? You should see something like `jshint v2.5.0` as a response if it's already in your path.

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you're like me, and can't modify your Windows  `PATH` variables due to workplace restrictions, you can add the path to the Default **and** User settings like I did here [Comment on SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/docs/issues/1#issuecomment-64037166). This worked for Sublime 3 build 3065.

```
{
    "default": {
        "debug": false,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "background",
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": ["C:/Users/myUserName/AppData/Roaming/npm"]
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "python django": "python",
            "html 5": "html",
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "php": "html"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, it helped me on a win 8 machine.